# Заполнение блока bootstrap фоновым изображением

Tags: bootstrap

Доброго времени суток, товарищи!
По ходу работы по верстке сайта столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Существует блок услуги. При просмотре в конфигурации большого (lg) экрана, все отображается как и задумано.

Но при уменьшении конфигурации размера экрана начинаются проблемы (md). Рисунок 1.

Рисунок 1.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется интервал снизу, при дальнейшем уменьшении размера экрана интервал только увеличивается(sm).
При переходе сетки в (xs) размер все отображается корректно, в столбик.

Собственно вопрос: существует ли способ заполнения блока col-sm-5 (там где содержится картинка) картинкой таким образом, что бы при изменении размера экрана не было появления интервала снизу, при учете заполненности соседнего блока текстом? Картинки предполагаются не произвольные, а преимущественно околоквадратного формата. Возможна привязка к четко определенному размеру картинки.

К сожалению не хватило репутации выложить полный код куска, надеюсь выразился понятно.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно самый простой способ устранить этот дефект - отключение промежуточных медиазапросов между стилями lg и xs

Answer (score 1):

Попробую предположить, может быть поможет...
Изображение можно обрезать дивом (), скрыть его часть, но это плохой вариант.
Лучше будет раздробить сетку так что бы изображение перепрыгивало над/под текст до появления пустоты.

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="col-xs-6">Ваш текст</div><div class="col-xs-6">Ваша картинка</div>
</div>
```

Как то так...

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку! К сожалению это проблему не решило, но идея хорошая :D Буду копать в эту сторону.