# Отключение медиазапроса Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, media-queries

Доброго времени суток!
Неоходим совет, каким образом я могу отключить два медиазапроса Bootstrap?
Суть проблемы в том, что мне необходимо заставить верстку работать на lg, затем перепргынуть через md,sm правила и сразу включить xs.

Мне видится это единственным способом решения проблемы, что возникла вот в этом моем вопросе:
[Заполнение блока bootstrap фоновым изображением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613107/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-bootstrap-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Возможно ли это реализовать без перекомпиляции библиотеки bootstrap?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то вас интересует ширина контейнера. тогда вы можете установить свою ширину с помощью своего css, который подключается после бутстрапа, типа

```
@media (min-width:768px){.container{width:742px}}
@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1140px}}
```

если интересует только ширина колонок, то используйте классы типа `class="col-lg-4 col-xs-6"`

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись!